# phono preamp input stage - exotic design

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp

I found a very exotic (at least for me) moving magnet input stage of a phono preamp. It's taken from an old cartridge measurement system from renown brand. I simply can't figure out the logic behind this circuit.

Applying "hot" signal to both inverting and non-inverting output? In what configuration does this op amp work?
Placing a large capacitor between the hot signal and the ground? Does it make any sense?

Any input and thoughts much appreciated.

[image: 4416]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applying "hot" signal to both inverting and non-inverting output? In what configuration does this op amp work?

Nope. Look again carefully. Left and Right inputs are applied to the non-inverting inputs of their pre-amplifiers.

> In what configuration does this op amp work?

I'll explain over one preamp since both preamps are identical.

- The input is closed with a 47k resistor.
- Anti-parallel 1N4148 diodes limit the input to the ±0.7Vpp.
- 1nF-100R pair provides frequency compensation *(Today's opamps are internally compensated but this **old** one requires compensation externally)*.
- The amplifier stage is nothing different from a non-inverting amplifier. The gain of this section is unity at DC thanks to the 150uF capacitor in series with 2k. At AC, this capacitor becomes short, so the net gain becomes A<sub>v</sub>=1 + 61k9 / 2k = 32. The 8p2  capacitor brings a high-cut in conjunction with 61k9 resistor. Its cut-off frequency is f<sub>C</sub> = (2 pi 61k9 8p2)<sup>-1</sup> = 313kHz.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

The input is only connected to the non-inverting input. There is no junction (wire connection with a dot) where the inverting side of the op-amp crosses over the input signal. R3 and C2 are not connected to the input, as well as R15 and C12. You're right it wouldn't make sense if they were.

Comment: thanks a million, now i can sleep during the nights

Answer (score 1):

Look at the circuit again: -

[image]

Because I think you are misinterpreting it.

Comment: thank you very much!